# Syntax to get sum(sales) group by brand but different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, aggregate-functions

My data is like so

```
item        date        country    sales
----------------------------------------
motorola    2015-01-01     US        10
motorola    2015-01-01     UK        20
motorola    2015-01-02     US        40
motorola    2015-01-02     UK        80
motorola    2015-01-03     US       120
motorola    2015-01-03     UK       150
motorola    2015-01-04     US       170
motorola    2015-01-04     US       180
```

I want to get the daily sales delta of motorola from 2 jan 2015 until 4 jan 2015.

So for example

- total sales for 1 jan 2015 is 10 (US) + 20(UK) = 30
- total sales for 2 jan 2015 is 120     so daily sales delta (sales on date minus D-1) is 90
- total sales for 3 jan 2015 is 270     so daily delta is 150
- total sales for 4 jan 2015 is 350     so daily delta is 80

I'm expecting the result tuple :

```
date         dailyDelta
2015-01-02      90
2015-01-03     150
2015-01-04      80
```

What is the syntax to get this? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: You can use the LAG() windowed function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it, the query logic is as simple as it gets, the performance better than inner joins:

```
select date, sum(sales) - coalesce(lag(sum(sales), 1) over (order by date), 0)
from my_sales
group by date
order by date
```

Use window function `lag`. Play with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bebab/8 and read about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

briefly, `lag(sum(sales), 1) over (order by date)` means "get sum(sales) column of previous record of this query, ordered by date", `coalesce(XXX, 0)` means "when XXX is null, let's pretend it was a zero"

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see much of a way around a self join. Here is how it would work:

```
select a.date
  , a.item
  , sum(a.sales) - sum(b.sales) as DailyDelta
from table a
  join table b on a.product = b.product
    and b.date = dateadd(day, -1, a.date)
group by a.date
  , a.item
```

Not great performance wise but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

The following query is based on MySQL, but you can tweak it to make it work for SQL server. I hope SQL Server will also support the same

```
select o.date, t.tsales - sum(sales) delta  from test o, (select date, sum(sales) tsales from test group by date) t
where o.date = t.date -1 group by o.date
```

For the above query I got the following result

"date"  "delta"
"2015-01-01"    "90"
"2015-01-02"    "150"
"2015-01-03"    "80"

Answer (score 0):

use a self join

```
declare @t table (item varchar(10), [date] date,country  char(2),  sales int)
insert into @t (item, [date],country,  sales) values
('motorola','2015-01-01','US',10),
('motorola','2015-01-01','UK',20),
('motorola','2015-01-02','US',40),
('motorola','2015-01-02','UK',80),
('motorola','2015-01-03','US',120),
('motorola','2015-01-03','UK',150),
('motorola','2015-01-04','US',170),
('motorola','2015-01-04','US',180)
;with a as (select row_number() over (order by [date]) r,[date],sum(sales) n from @t group by [date]) 

select a.[date],a.n-isnull(a1.n,0) dailyDelta from a  join a a1 on a.r =a1.r+1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

SELECT date,

```
  ( sum(sales) - LAG(sum(sales),1,0) over (order by sales) ) as dailyDelta
```

FROM Table

group by date

order by date;